# Assetic:dump works incorrect when bundle templates are overriden

Tags: symfony, handlebars.js, assetic

Bundle templates in Symfony2 can be overriden according to the docs
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates
Recently we found that Assetic (probably) is not aware of that scenario.

Let's look to the following structure:

the bundle itself:

- /src/XXX/MyBundle/Resources

  - public

    - template.hbs
  - views

    - Default

      - template.html.twig

and its overrides:

- /app/Resources/XXXMyBundle/

  - public

    - template.hbs
  - views

    - Default

      - template.html.twig

Template.html.twig (both original one from bundle and the override) contain the following code:

```
{% javascripts output='js/hbs/templates.js'
    '@XXXMyBundle/Resources/public/template.hbs'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Now, it would be logical that when dumping the assets, assetic also looked for possible overrides, in our example it is
/app/Resources/XXXMyBundle/public/template.hbs

but as my testing shows, it always compiles the one from /src folder

Probably, when analyzing the notation '@XXXMyBundle/Resources/public/template.hbs', assetic does not check if @XXXMyBundle may have overrides in /app folder.

Comment: Why would you expect of Assetic to look in your `public` directory? It's supposed to look only in `views/*`, if I remember correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you found [this document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates), but everything written here applies only to templates. This logic is very simple, you can check it in [TemplateFinder](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/CacheWarmer/TemplateFinder.php#L50) in FrameworkBundle.